# Clickbank api not authenticating

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

Despite of assigning right API key and Dev key click bank does not authenticate my application to authenticate. It rturns 403 forbidden message.

What is the wrong with my script?

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/validateDeveloperKey");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//for security reasons these are not real keys
    $dev_key="DEV-9E4ABEDD687A7893D3E61CDE7009D4900CB0";
    $api_key= "API-02BFF7786901A18D9Y5FAAAD3853435AE646";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml", "Authorization: ".$dev_key.":". $api_key));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print $result;
```

Comment: Perhaps Clickbank is applying the [same payment processing rules as Paypal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014208/paypal-checkout-issue) and refusing to handle payments from or to your country?

Answer (score 1):

When troubleshooting ClickBank issues, it's very important to point out whether the problem requests are occuring during "live transactions" on the API server (https://api.clickbank.com) or, rather, during "test transactions" on the Sandbox server (https://sandbox.clickbank.com).

OP appears to be testing ClickBank functionality by sending requests to the live ClickBank server, instead of the testing server.

As the previous answer indicates, the CURLOPT_URL line should read:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/validateDeveloperKey");
```

Furthermore, the Developer and API keys presented in the OP do not appear to be Sandbox keys which are suitable for use on the Sandbox server. Instead, they are the main Developer and API keys which should be used for performing real transactions on the live API server.

A ClickBank API Sandbox Developer Key has the following format:

DEV-SB-4900BEDD687A7893D3E61CDE7009D4900CB0

The OP's developer key does not contain the "-SB-" part, which would indicate that it is not a Sandbox key.

The first step involved in utilizing the ClickBank Sandbox server is to "prepare" a ClickBank API Sandbox environment. Here is the documentation for that method from ClickBank https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox:

> POST  /1.2/sandbox/prepare - Prepare a sandbox environment.
>
> It will create a sandbox developer key and return it to the end user. Note
>   that the user must have a valid production developer key in the Authorization
>   header to access this API.
>
> Return Type: SandboxDeveloperData
>
> Supported Output Types : application/xml, application/json

To reiterate, before you can begin sending test code to the ClickBank Sandbox Server, you must first request a ClickBank Sandbox Developer Key by POST'ing a PREPARE request to the correct Sandbox URL. The 'prepare' request must contain a valid ClickBank Master Developer Key in the Authorization header, or else it will fail.

Moving on, The previous answer also correctly points out that although ClickBank's own PHP example says to use the curl options parameter CURLOPT_GET, no such curl parameter actually exists. The correct parameter to set is CURLOPT_HTTPGET, if you are attempting to specify a GET request.

Having said all of that, YMMV. Not much documentation exists about ClickBank's API, and what little information there is from ClickBank contains errors. It's possible that once you've debugged your code, you will still get 403 returns from the Sandbox server for no apparent reason.

Finally, one tool which has become invaluable to me when working with REST services is   "rest-client" http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

rest-client allows you to test GET, POST, and HEAD requests to any REST service before you've ever written line one of code.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is a month old, and doesn't have an answer yet.  I hope you have found the answer by now, however if you have not, there are a couple of problems with your request:

First:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/validateDeveloperKey");
```

Should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/validateDeveloperKey");
```

Note:
I have not received a successful response on that query (gives me a 405 Method Not Allowed response).

Second:
There is no CURLOPT_GET.  If you have changed the method (ie CURLOPT_POST), you can reset it by using CURLOPT_HTTPGET, otherwise it is GET by default. (and yes, the php example shows CURLOPT_GET, but it does not exist in the manual), if you turn on E_NOTICE you will see that failure

I am not sure why the validateDeveloperKey does not work, however I have had success with all the other sandbox requests (all POST's work).  I am curious if there is a new API version (above 1.2) as I have read posts talking about 2.1 in my google searches.

That may not answer your question exactly, but I hope if you are still having issues, that the notes I provided help you.

Thanks/Aaron

Update: On further research: in order to send a HEAD request (validateDeveloperKey) you must set the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Otherwise it sends it as a GET request (as I was mentioning above).  It works with generated sandbox developer keys (returns 204 No Content), however with my actual developer key it returns 403 Forbidden.

Again, I hope this helps.