# Paypal Checkout issue

Tags: paypal, oscommerce, paypal-sandbox

I sell digital products using Paypal website payment standard. Everything is ok except that paypal checkout does not proceed stating the following error:
"PayPal does not allow your country of residence to deliver to the country you wish to"

I want to disable any shipping related things and I m using osCommerce

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove the shipping method and cash on delivery method

Answer (score 0):

This is not a shipping issue - it's related to money transfer, which is prohibited by the laws of either your country or the recipient's country.

Answer (score 0):

You're both right (Scott and Navane); the country the buyer selected on Cheetah's site differs from the country the PayPal account of the buyer was registered in. This works fine in some cases (US delivery address with Canadian PayPal account) but can fail in others (Singapore address with UK account).